# Can I download, re-sign, and distribute a Windows Store app across an organisation?

Tags: store

We have a situation where we're like to distribute a free-to-download Windows Store app to ~1,000 users across an organisation.

Currently the approach is for each user to log in to the store individually and download the app.

Would it be possible to download the xap file once, re-sign it, and distribute it using intune?

A similar method is described here, but it may just be for in house developed apps:

[Channel 9 - Deploying Windows Phone apps for the Enterprise](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Inside+Windows+Phone/IWP72-Deploying-Windows-Phone-apps-for-the-Enterprise)

Answer (score 3):

You can create an application in Windows Intune pointing to the actual app in the store, and deploy that to your devices:

1. In the Configuration Manager console, click Software Library.
2. In the Software Library workspace, expand Application Management, and then click Applications.
3. In the Home tab, in the Create group, click Create Application.
4. On the General page of the Create Application Wizard, select Automatically detect information about this application from installation files.
5. In the Type drop-down, select the app package for your device type.
6. Click Browse to open the store, select the app you want to include, and then click Next.
7. On the General Information page, enter the descriptive text and category information that you want users to see in the company portal.
8. Complete the wizard.

For more information, visit [this technet page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469410.aspx) and checkout the section *To create an application containing a link to a store.*

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer. We'll test this and update with details on how we get on.

Comment: We tested this approach, and it does work. However each user still needs their own Windows Store id.

Answer (score 1):

We got a response directly from Microsoft on this.

Apparently the XAP file you download from the Windows Store includes copy protection, so it is not possible to resign and distribute one using an enterprise deployment certificate.